# Back To My Mac access through router without UPnP or NAT-PMP support?

Tags: network, back-to-my-mac

Will having a router at one end, but not the other, supporting UPnP or NAT-PMP be enough to initiate Back To My Mac connections in *both* directions? That is, also in the direction of a computer behind the router that does *not* support UPnP or NAT-PMP?

The Apple [knowledge base article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4907) on setting up Back To My Mac lists an "AirPort base station (AirPort Extreme, AirPort Express, or AirPort Time Capsule) or other Internet router that supports UPnP or NAT-PMP" as one of the requirements.  It does not seem to explicitly state that routers on *both* ends must support UPnP or NAT-PMP.

Comment: 3 questions... all essentially the same subject from the same user.   When you want to update a questions it should be [edited](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/142963/edit).

Comment: Tyson: These are three different technical questions about Back To My Mac and routers.

Comment: Instead of asking very detailed questions it might yield better answers if you focus on describing the real-world problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: patrix: The real-world problem, as already described in the original question, is that I need to know if Back To My Mac is supposed to work in both directions when only one of the routers support UPnP or NAT-PMP.

Comment: The answers will be better if we could focus on exactly this point for the moment. If things aren't clear from the answers at first, it would then be better to improve the answers by asking for clarifications in the comments.

Comment: I moved the question to the first paragraph and instead put the background information with the reference to the Apple knowledge base article in the second paragraph. I hope this puts the focus on the problem I'm trying to solve.